# Postman gives an error, not updating image

Tags: image, postman, crud, laravel-10

I used Laravel API CRUD postman

All information is created in the Store but Update doesn't want                   to update anything. I tried different versions of the code but Postman gives the same message:

> Information in postman is not updated

What is wrong with this code?

---

This is my Request:

```
class UpdateProductRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'   => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
        'description'  => 'required', 'text',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'price' => 'required', 'float',
        'category_id' => 'nullable',
        'ingredient_id' => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```

---

Update

```
public function update(UpdateProductRequest $request, Product $product): JsonResponse
    {

        $imageName = '';
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file->extension();
            $request->file->storeAs('public/img', $imageName);
            if ($product->image) {
                Storage::delete('public/img' . $product->image);
            }
        } else {
            $imageName = $product->image;
        }

        $data = [
            'title' => $request->title,
            'image' => $imageName,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'ingredient_id' => $request->ingredient_id,

        ];
        $product->update($data);

        return $this->sendResponse(new ProductResource($product), 'Product updated successfully.');



   
       //error in postman

    {
    "message": "The title field is required. (and 3 more errors)",
    "errors": {
        "title": [
            "The title field is required."
        ],
        "description": [
            "The description field is required."
        ],
        "image": [
            "The image field is required."
        ],
        "price": [
            "The price field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the request really look like? Did you submit the fields that Laravel moans about?